# Send email to multiple recipient

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, phpmailer

i am using CI as framework and PhpMailer as email sender.
Building a project for notification, in which i am generating mail List which at least consists of (600 emails). But here i am restricted to send email to multiple recipient at one go by the google.

could anyone please suggest optimal way of doing it or any third party tool in php, javascript or jquery for doing it.

Comment: This is a very vague question - you should be showing us what you have tried. Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). It's generic PHP, but the approach will work fine with CI. Also read [the notes about sending to lists](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists). This won't solve your gmail imitations, but you should perhaps look at using a better email service for that.

Comment: You can just loop over the number of he recipients and send he email. Assuming your data comes from a database, you just need to fetch the data and change the values (to,subject,body,etc). It's not complicated. The issue is not how to send the email. You have to design in database level your notification system, which is the most time consuming and complicated part.

Comment: If you're being rate-limited by gmail, which is actually very reasonable, and you need to send emails in bulk, you'll be much more comfortable using an email delivery service such as mailgun, sendgrid, sendinblue, etc. Code based approaches may somewhat work but nothing can really work around rate limiting from the outgoing email server

Answer (score 0):

If you store emails in the database, you can try the solutions below. Here I assume the email is stored in a table called members and an querying database using PDO.
The code below can be modified to adapt to your needs

```
<?php



$db = new PDO (
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb_name-goes-here;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username

    '' // password
);


// get emails from database via PDO
$result = $db->prepare('
            SELECT email FROM  members');

        $result->execute(array());
while ($row = $result->fetch()){
$id= $row['id'];
$email = $row['email'];



$j=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=count($id); $i++) {


// send email here in multiple
$to=$email;
$subject = "Hello you have Message from Nancy";
$message = 'my message goes here';
$from = "yourdomain@eample.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$sent=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 if($sent)  {
print "<br><font color=green><b>Your mail was sent Successfully</b></font>";
 } else  {
print "<br><font color=orange><b>We encountered an error sending your mail</b></font>";

 }




    $j++;




}

}


?>
```